# Retrieving data based on One To Many Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-many, laravel-5.8, laravel-relations

I have two tabled called `categories` and `resources` table.

Basically each resource has a category and the category id is saved on a column called `resource_category_id` in `resources` table.

So in order to setup One To Many relationship between the Models, I did these:

**`Category`**:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = "categories";
    protected $guarded = [];
    
    public function resources()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Resource::class);
    }
}
```

**`Resource`**:

```
class Resource extends Model
{
    protected $table = "resources";
    protected $guarded = [];
    
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'resource_category_id');
    }
}
```

And now I want to show all categories and the resources and that have the same `resource_category_id` like this:

```
@php($menuCounter = 0)
@foreach($categories as $cat)
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center">{{ ++$menuCounter }}</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">{{ $cat->category_name }}</td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                @foreach($category->resources() as $resource)
                    <li><a href="{{ $resource->resource_link }}">{{ $ress->resource_name }}</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

But now the categories are all appearing but the resources does not be shown and also no error returns!

So what's going wrong here?

How can I show the resources according to `resource_category_id` via Eloquent relationships methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
@foreach($category->resources() as $resource)
```

do

```
@foreach($category->resources as $resource)
```

The first one is loading the builder, the second one the collection.

You can also specify the foreign key for resources relationship in Category Model:

```
public function resources()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Resource::class, 'resource_category_id');
}
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'resources.resource_category_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Edited my answer - add foreign key to resources relationship